# Error 3200002: invalid http response Error Details: Invalid content-length response

Tags: nodeos, cleos, keosd

Everything was working fine till Saturday evening. But when I tried to open wallet using `cleos wallet open` So it throws 3200002 error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what was the issue. But when I followed whole process of [EOSIO installation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/setting-up-your-environment), then it solved the issue and it started working again.